# How do I replace VARIABLE in the help output: `--argument VARIABLE` in python's argparse.?

Tags: python, argparse

I have a terminal app, powered by `argparse`, which provides some mutually exclusive arguments:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Control EC2 instances from your terminal.')
g = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

g.add_argument('--create', help='Make a fresh instance.')
g.add_argument('--start')
# ...

args = parser.parse_args()
```

However the problem I have is, on the help output, it shows:

```
[--create CREATE | --start START |
# ...
--create CREATE       Make a fresh instance.
--start START
```

What do I need to add to the `add_argument` line, so each one shows litterally:

```
--start <instance-id>
```

Instead of the capitalized string `START`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this is to use:

```
g.add_argument('--start', metavar='<instance-id>')
```